# type mismatch looping through shapes

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm getting a type mismatch 13 error in the line that loops through the shapes in a slide. I can see that the `oSh` is `Nothing`, but if I `.Count` the shapes, there are plenty of shapes in the slide. How does this make sense?

**Brief code:**

```
Dim oPP As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oS As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
For Each oS In oPP.Slides
    For Each oSh In oS.Shapes '<-- this line is the error line
        On Error Resume Next
        If oSh.Type = 14 _
                Or oSh.Type = 1 Then
            'do stuff            
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next oSh
Next oS
```

**Full code:**

```
Sub PPLateBinding()
    Dim pathString As String
    'no reference required
    Dim PowerPointApplication As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPP As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oS As Slide
    Dim oSh As Object
    Dim pText As String
    Dim cellDest As Integer
    Dim arrBase() As Variant
    Dim arrComp() As Variant
    ReDim Preserve arrBase(1)
    ReDim Preserve arrComp(1)

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim FileChosen As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim iPresentations As Integer

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    'use the standard title and filters, but change the
    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    'allow multiple file selection
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If FileChosen = -1 Then
    'open each of the files chosen
    For iPresentations = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        'On Error Resume Next
        Set PowerPointApplication = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        Set oPP = PowerPointApplication.Presentations.Open(fd.SelectedItems(iPresentations))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set oPP = Nothing
        End If

        If Not (oPP Is Nothing) Then
            cellDest = 0

            'We assume PP is already open and has an active presentation
            For Each oS In oPP.Slides
                'Debug.Print oPP.Slides.Count
                If oS.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print oS.Shapes.Count
                        For Each oSh In oS.Shapes
                            Debug.Print "hey"
                            On Error Resume Next
                            If oSh.Type = 14 Or oSh.Type = 1 Then
                                pText = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                                ReDim Preserve arrBase(UBound(arrBase) + 1)
                                arrBase(UBound(arrBase)) = pText
                                    'Debug.Print pText
                            ElseIf (oSh.HasTable) Then
                                Dim i As Integer
                                For i = 2 To oSh.Table.Rows.Count
                                    ReDim Preserve arrComp(UBound(arrComp) + 1)
                                    arrComp(UBound(arrComp)) = Replace(oSh.Table.Cell(i, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, vbLf, "") & ":::" & oSh.Table.Cell(i, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                                Next i
                            End If
                            On Error GoTo 0
                        Next oSh
                    'x = InputData(arrBase, arrComp)
                End If
            Next oS

            'Debug.Print tbl.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text '.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextRange.Text
            oPP.Close
            PowerPointApplication.Quit
            Set oPP = Nothing
            Set PowerPointApplication = Nothing
        End If
    Next iPresentations
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you should initialize your `oS`  object (slide)

Comment: @simoco - my bad, I forgot to paste it from my code, but it's there

Comment: can you show your full code? right now I don't see where do you initialize `oPP` and if you're using this code from excel, there should be also a variable representing `PowerPoint.Application`

Comment: @simoco - sure I only shortphrased it for convenience. I've added the full code below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excel has its own `Shape` type (which is not the same as `PowerPoint.Shape` type), so you should change

```
Dim oSh As Shape
```

to (for earlier binding)

```
Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape
```

or (for late binding)

```
Dim oSh As Object
```

Also note, if you're going to use powerpoint with late binding (as suggests your function name `Sub PPLateBinding()`), you should change all types `PowerPoint.Something` to `Object` (unless you add reference to powerpoint object model, but in this case I don't see any reason for using late binding).

Comment: Expert eye I must say. I actually had this originally, but the problem is that I got another error namely Object Required 494, but only when I select multiple files. Maybe you can help me with that too?

Comment: yeah, you should make two little changes: 1) cut this line `Set PowerPointApplication = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")` from loop and paste it just after `If FileChosen = -1 Then`. 2) cut lines `PowerPointApplication.Quit` and `Set PowerPointApplication = Nothing` from loop and paste them just after `Next iPresentations`